# Android Emulator hanging up with 8000M of RAM

Tags: android

Replication steps from a fresh install:

1. Download extract the android cmd-tools
2. Run the following script in the same directory as `cmdline-tools` folder.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

ANDROID_AVD_HOME="$SCRIPT_DIR/.android/avd" command "$SCRIPT_DIR/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager" \
    --sdk_root="$SCRIPT_DIR/sdk" "cmdline-tools;latest" "platform-tools" "emulator" \
    "system-images;android-34;google_apis_playstore;x86_64" "system-images;android-32;android-desktop;x86_64" \
    "platforms;android-34" "platform-tools"

ANDROID_AVD_HOME="$SCRIPT_DIR/.android/avd" command "$SCRIPT_DIR/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager" create avd -n androidvm -k "system-images;android-34;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$SCRIPT_DIR/sdk/" ANDROID_AVD_HOME="$SCRIPT_DIR/.android/avd" command \
    "$SCRIPT_DIR/sdk/emulator/emulator" @androidvm -qemu -enable-kvm -m 8000M
```

Problem:
Get errors like System UI not responding and never can do anything in the application.